# How to change default value of a subclass attribute in java

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, default

this is my main class and i want to change the default value of

The default values of the remaining attributes should be as follows:

- hp: defaultHP
- ip: defaultIP
- traitCooldown: 0
- inventory: empty
- spells: empty

with certain values

```
package harrypotter.model.character;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import harrypotter.model.magic.Collectible;
import harrypotter.model.magic.Spell;

public abstract class Wizard {
    private String name;
    private int defaultHp;
    private int defaultIp;
    private int hp=defaultHp ;  
    private int ip=defaultIp;
    private ArrayList<Spell> spells;
    private ArrayList<Collectible> inventory;
    private Point location;
    private int traitCooldown;  

    public Wizard(String name) {            
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getDefaultHp() {
        return defaultHp;
    }
    public void setDefaultHp(int defaultHp) {
        this.defaultHp = defaultHp;
    }

    public int getDefaultIp() {
        return defaultIp;
    }

    public void setDefaultIp(int defaultIp) {
        this.defaultIp = defaultIp;
    }

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }
    public void setHp(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
    }
    public int getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
    public void setIp(int ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public int getTraitCooldown() {
        return traitCooldown;
    }
    public void setTraitCooldown(int traitCooldown) {
        this.traitCooldown = traitCooldown;
    }
    public ArrayList<Spell> getSpells() {
        return spells;
    }
    public ArrayList<Collectible> getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }
}
```

the subclass with my try

```
package harrypotter.model.character;    

public class GryffindorWizard extends Wizard implements Champion {

public GryffindorWizard(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.setHp(900);
        this.setIp(500);
        this.setTraitCooldown(0);
        this.getInventory();
        this.getSpells();
    }

    public void useTrait() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 }
```

Comment: Some code, but no real question?

Comment: i don't know how to change the default value of each wizard so how do i set the defaultHp and defaultIp in the subclass?

Comment: Hint: you hope that other people spend their time to help you solve your problem. It would be polite then to give feedback; like "yes, this helps" (for example by upvoting/accepting); or giving some comments. In any case: if you consider accepting my answer - feel free to wait until tomorrow; as I already hit the daily cap today.

Answer (score 0):

Funny. You figured to go for:

```
 this.setHp(900);
 this.setIp(500);
```

So, why not go for:

```
 this.setDefaultHp(900);
 this.setDefaultIp(500);
```

And for the record; these assignments

```
private int defaultHp;
private int defaultIp;
private int hp=defaultHp ;  
private int ip=defaultIp;
```

are executed **once** when a new object is created; so all **4** fields will have a value of **0** upon creation. In other words: when you want to initialize hp and ip with some *meaningful* defaults; then consider using non-0 values there!